# VerticalTab Material React UI está sendo sobreposto pelo conteúdo da tab

Tags: html, css, material-ui

Estou tentando utilizar [este componente](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/tabs/#guias-verticais) de guias-verticais, porém quando insiro um conteúdo grande ele está sobrepondo minha vertical-tab conforme você pode ver [nesta demonstração](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gr046?file=/demo.js)

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        className={classes.tabs}
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        <Tab label="Item Four" {...a11yProps(3)} />
        <Tab label="Item Five" {...a11yProps(4)} />
        <Tab label="Item Six" {...a11yProps(5)} />
        <Tab label="Item Seven" {...a11yProps(6)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            ELemento 1 sadasdasdasdasdadadad
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            Elemento 2 sadasdasdasdasdasdasd dsadasdasdsadasdsadasdadaddsadasd
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item one
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
);
```

Como podem ver, o conteúdo presente nas minhas `<Grid>` estão sobrepondo as `<Tabs>` quando o tamanho é grande, há algum outro elemento que devo usar no lugar da `<Grid>` para que o conteúdo não sobreponha o outro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola,

Você até pode manter com os componentes que você fez,o que está acontecendo é que as Guias e o conteudo são renderizados em elementos divs simples sem aplicação de CSS's que tratam adequadamente a sobreposição dos elementos empurrando/espremendo o conteudo.

Aqui uma demonstração semelhante, porém aplicando as correções com uso de classes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3ej9j

Uma dica, se atente sempre a como os elementos do Material-UI são renderizados(abuse-use das ferramentas de dev-tools para inspecionar os elementos gerados), isso ajuda a compreender como os elementos estão dispostos no html.